# NSUserDefaults, One Preference with three options 

Tags: cocoa, nsuserdefaults

Thanks for the help.

I'm having a hard time with a preference that has three options by way of checkboxes. More specifically, the relationship between the bool states of three checkboxes that control the preference.  I comfortable setting up single checkbox preferences, and the individual preference settings in this three option version all work. However I can't seem to get the checkboxes to interact consistently. So one on, two off, etc.

This is my code. What's the best way to get this done?

Thanks.

Paul

```
- (BOOL)displayBankOne


 {
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 return [defaults boolForKey:PREFdisplayBankOne];

}

- (IBAction)bankOne:(id)sender

{


 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 [defaults setBool:displayBankOne forKey:PREFdisplayBankOne];

 [defaults setBool:displayBankOne forKey:PREFdisplayBankOne];
 [defaults setBool:displayBankTwo forKey:PREFdisplayBankTwo];
 [defaults setBool:displayBankThree forKey:PREFdisplayBankThree];

 [bankOneFlag setState:NSOnState];

 [bankTwoFlag setState:NSOffState];
 [bankThreeFlag setState:NSOffState];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you could try using a Radio Group (NSMatrix). Instead of 3 individual check boxes. And use the binding in IB to bind their  *Value Selection*  to the shared User Defaults.

In binding in IB, (Matrix bindings) Just tick **bind to:** shared User Defaults Controller.
And give the pref entry a name in the **Model Key Path**.

To give you an idea:i
You can even bind other Objects to the same **Model Key Path** name. i.e 
you can add a Label (NSTextField) in IB, and bind its value to the shared User Defaults Controller. And set its *Value* **Model Key Path** to the same name you gave the name in the **Model Key Path** for the Radio Group.

When run, the Label will display the index number of which radio button is on.